# Is that possible to divide all elements in C# double list to that double list elements sum (which makes total = 1)

Tags: c#, list, element, divide

Imagine a doube list like the follow

```
List<double> lstDouble=new List<double>{4,6,2,7,1,1};
```

So what i want is dividing all elements in this list to sum of the elements(21).

So the list becomes after dividing :

```
lstDouble = {4/21,6/21,2/21,7/21,1/21,1/21}
```

Which would mean that the new sum of the elements = 1

I can do that via iteration etc but i wonder are there any short way since Matlab has. And my assistant professor keep telling me that learn Matlab and use it but i don't want :D I love C#

Thank you.

C# 4.0 WPF application

Comment: Note that the sum will be approximately 1 afterwards, and not exactly 1. Depending on the values the approximation might be pretty bad.

Comment: That is not very important it will be close 1 though.

Comment: Do you want to modify the input array, or do you want to return a new, modified array?

Comment: I handled that       lstTempDouble = lstTempDouble.Select(x => x / sum).ToList<double>();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var sum = lstDouble.Sum();
var result = lstDouble.Select(d => d / sum);
```

- [Enumerable.Sum Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx)
- [Enumerable.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with LINQ:

```
var sum = lstDouble.Sum();
var newLst = lstDouble.Select( x => x/sum );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda expression:

```
 lstDouble.ForEach(x => x = x/21);
```

Comment: `21` is a variable number that depends on the size and values of the array.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sum = lstDouble.Sum();
var result = lstDouble.Select(v => v / sum);
```

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yeah, thought of that just after I posted. Corrected. Now I have the same answer as everybody else here :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pseudo code:

```
double sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   sum+=array[i];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   array[i]=array[i]/sum;
```

Comment: down vote is supposed to mean the code would not work. So why the negative vote?

Comment: even that does not warrant a down vote. The poster could figure it out from there.

Comment: downvote means the answer is "not useful".  the question states "I can do that via iteration", which is what this answer is doing, which makes this answer not useful in the context of the question.